# How to utilize code analysis with no default branch

Tags: static-analysis, devops

I'm currently trying to setup some code analysis for my team however I found our release process does not mesh well with the tools I have looked into (CodeClimate and SonarQube). Both tools require a default branch to track the state or "grade" of your repository over time. They watch the default branch and analyze pull requests to that branch. However, our current release process involves a new branch for each release which we merge into master after the branch is released. We could use master as our default branch but we would not see the analysis until after the code is out which is not ideal. As I am not in a position to change our process, I am tasked with finding a tool or work around to get an analysis tool to work with our process. The only work around I could think of is two pull requests. One to the release branch as usual, and another to master just to trigger the analysis. The master PR would then be closed once the issues found in the analysis are fixed. This is far from ideal and I come to my favorite forum looking for help and experience.

Code is in Github.

Primary language to analyze is PHP, bonus languages are CSS, JS, and Java.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like [Codacy](https://www.codacy.com/) could be a good alternative.

You can enable the analysis on all the branches of your project. All the pull requests to an analysed branch will be analysed, even if it's not the default branch.

It supports all the required languages: PHP, JS, CSS, Java and more. It also has a nice [auto-comment integration](https://github.com/paypal/squbs/pull/121) with Github to help you save more time in code reviews.

Comment: This looks great man. I'll dive into it and see if this is my fix. I figured it would be just a matter of finding the right tool. I'll mark as answer once I check it out

Comment: Tried it out, tool appears great. But it seems to be a little young, had quite a few bugs trying it out.